# Display difference between two dates using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to display the difference between two dates in a text box using JavaScript. I tried the following code but it did not work:

```
function showdatediff(){
    //get value of  the two dates
    var date1 = document.getElementById('date1').value;
    var date2 = document.getElementById('date2').value;
    //cheack the diffrence
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    document.bookform.displaytextbox.value = (diffDays);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind including an external library, maybe consider [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

It supports finding the [difference between 2 dates](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/).

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
var date1 = document.getElementById('date1').value;
var date2 = document.getElementById('date2').value;
//var milliseconds = moment(date1).diff(moment(date2));
var days = moment(date2).diff(moment(date1), 'days');
document.bookform.displaytextbox.value = days;
</script>
```

Comment: thanks man, that was wow... it worked..

Comment: Glad to hear it. :) Any chance you could mark this as the answer?

Comment: You just click the tick mark on the left (below the arrows around the number). You get some points for it too. :)